# How to add some numbers to an array in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have `JSON` :

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "info": [
            { "total": 3000 },
            { "total": 2000 },
            { "total": 5000 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 1,
        "info": [
            { "total": 6000 },
            { "total": 4000 },
            { "total": 1000 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "info": [
            { "total": 1000 },
            { "total": 8000 },
            { "total": 2000 }
        ]
    }
]
```

In each item there is an array called `info`. Every object of this array would be shown as an input by type=radio.

Each Input has an `onclick` function called `handleCheck()`.

There is a state called `AddValue` that is an array by default.

When running `handleCheck()` I want the value of input `(total)` to be added to the array `AddValue` according to the check state of the input.

For example user start to check the inputs of first object `(index: 0)` , `AddValue` should contain the value of input that are checked like this : `[5000,3000]`.

But I get this error :

`_this5.state.AddValue.push is not a function`

What I did is here:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            AddValue: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/json.bc', {
            method: 'get',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                this.setState(state => ({
                    ...state,
                    data: text
                }), () => {
                    this.reorganiseLibrary()
                })
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
    ...

    renderLibrary = () => {
        const { library } = this.state;
        if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
            return '';
        }
        return library.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.index}>
                {this.renderInfo(item.Info, item.index)}
                <input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue[index]} />
            </div>
        ))
    }
    render() {
        const { library } = this.state;
        return (
            this.renderLibrary()
        )
    }
    renderInfo(elemen, index) {
        for (let i = 0; i < elemen.Info.length; i++) {
            return <input type="radio" value={element.info[i].total} onClick={((e) => this.handleCheck(e, index))} />

        }
    }
    handleCheck = (e, index) => {
        var isChecked = e.target.checked
        var value = e.target.value
        if (isChecked) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                AddValue: {
                    ...prevState.AddValue, [index]: this.state.AddValue.concat(value)
                },
            }))

        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Comment: AddValue is an object `{}` not an array `[]`.

Comment: But I want to be an array, It is defined as an array in state: `AddValue: []`

Comment: AddValue: { ... } -> that should be AddValue: [ ... ]. Plus I don't understand why you're adding the whole array again under index.

Comment: As you can see In JSON  there is 3 main objects. Every item has `{this.state.AddValue}` that should be contains of `total` of own items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the update function in handleCheck should be like this. It's an array.

```
  this.setState(prevState => ({
   AddValue: [
   ...prevState.AddValue,
   value
  ]
 }))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there are two issues .Firstly for eample for object that index =0 `AddValue` by checking all input should be like this : `Array(3) [ 5000, 2000,3000 ]` next the inputs of object by index =1 will be checked `AddValue` should be like this:`Array(3) [ 4000, 6000,1000 ]` but by your code is like this : `Array(6) [ 5000, 2000,3000,4000, 6000,1000 ]` because of this I use `index` in my code

Comment: @mona so the contents of the array should be replaced by the new value?

Comment: Ne I mean  every item is going to have `{this.state.AddValue}`  and every array should be contained the total of thats item. For instance the value of `<input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue} />` for item index = 0 should be Array(2) [ 5000, 2000 ] (two inputs are checked) , the value of `<input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue} />` for item index = 2 should be Array(3) [ 1000, 2000, 8000 ] (three inputs are checked)

Comment: But they are all using the same array `<input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue} />`. Shouldn't it be `this.state.AddValue[index]` or something?

Comment: Yes I changed   `<input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue} /> ` to `<input type="hidden" value={this.state.AddValue[index]} /> ` but nothing has changed

Comment: I wrote ` this.setState(prevState => ({
AddValue: [
   ...prevState.AddValue[index],
   value
  ]
 }))` but does not work

Comment: So, you want the content of AddValue to be like this `[{ index: 0, value: [a,b,c]},{ index: 1, value: [a,b,]}, ...so on]` ?